# Symfony production displays files inside the web folder than than going to the route

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I am working on deploying the symfony app and this is not the first time i am doing it but for some reason this time all i see on production is the list of files inside the `web` folder rather than a home route.

[image]

I dont know what I am forgeting, i have gone through my checklist over and over and over but i cant seem to find out whats wrong this time.

Here is my `classifieds.maindomain.com.conf` file may be this will give some clue

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName classifieds.maindomain.com
        ServerAlias www.classifieds.main.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/maindomain.com/subdomains/classifieds/web
        <Directory /var/www/html/maindomain.com/subdomains/classifieds/web>
            AllowOverride All
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from All
        </Directory>
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I will extremely appreciate any help here as i am pulling my hairs now.

Comment: Did you install symfony 2 and set the permissions right?

Comment: I think so because if i go to `classifieds.maindomain.com/app.php` it seems to be showing me the home route

Comment: Did you enabled your virutal host and reloaded your webserver?

Comment: yes i enabled the virtual host and reloaded the server

Answer (score 0):

It is because By default, Ubuntu's Apache will ignore the directives in your .htaccess files.
This link [Enabling Use Of Apache Htaccess Files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles) will help you or
maybe your `ROOT_DIR/web/.htaccess` file have a problem.

Comment: I already have so many sites working on the configuration i have this is the only one that seems to be giving me a problem and i dont remember following these steps for any site

Comment: I have the same problem and this link helped me to solve it. @Baig

Answer (score 0):

Make this change under Directory directive see if that works:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/maindomain.com/subdomains/classifieds/web>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from All
</Directory>
```

Not certain if that will fix it, but that's what I have from [my reference blog](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/05/11/apache-symfony-on-rhel/).